# Error in java expected : : in switch-case

Tags: java

I have such a switch-case, inside which the lambda of the function swears at -> (expects ":"), how can I fix it, provided that I have lambda expressions there?

```
switch (exp.getOperator()) {
    case "+" -> {
        lastVar = "%add" + addCounter++;
        lastVarType = "Int";
        operation = "add";
    }
    case "-" -> {
        lastVar = "%sub" + subCounter++;
        lastVarType = "Int";
        operation = "sub";
    }
    case "*" -> {
        lastVar = "%mul" + mulCounter++;
        lastVarType = "Int";
        operation = "mul";
    }
    case "/" -> {
        lastVar = "%div" + divCounter++;
        lastVarType = "Int";
        operation = "div";
    }
}
```

Comment: By using Java 12 or above.

Comment: Which Java version are you using, and which Java version is your compilation targetting?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch switch expressions where preview only in Java 12, it was only finalized in Java 14.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel They weren't present at all before Java 12. But fair enough.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True, but using them in Java 12 and 13 requires enabling preview features.

Comment: Note: that is NOT a lambda (even if it looks like it) - it is just a switch statement using Switch Rules